# Android AppBarLayout pushes ViewPager down

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have below `xml` file which has 1)Toolbar 2)TabLayout 3)Custom View and 4) ViewPager. When i put `Toolbar`, `TabLayout`, `Custom View` inside `AppBarLayout`, it pushes `ViewPager` down as like this:

[image]

`xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/feed_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorAccent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_alt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary_color"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/feed_sliding_tabs_alt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/accent_color"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/accent_color_per_70" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_feed_fl_canli_skor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mac_back"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activity_feed_alt_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_feed_new_post"
        android:theme="@style/FabTheme"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/feed_coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When i scroll down, `Toolbar` gets hidden which is good. But My `ViewPager`  overflows main screen and bottom of `ViewPager` is not visible. What can i try?

When i scroll up `Toolbar` gets invisible and `ViewPager` is pulled up and fully visible in screen. But `Toolbar` only responds to scroll of 1st page of `ViewPager`. **trick: For now i put paddingBottom to frament inside ViewPager**

Comment: Ran into the same issue and had to remove the CoordinatorLayout and replace it with a LinearLayout to allow the ViewPager not overflow the screen. For me that is easier to do that. Might not be the best solution for others though.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you managed to fix it ?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev nope, just adding padding to the bottom of fragment inside ViewPager, so bottom of the fragment will be visible

Comment: I opened an issue regarding this here, please shar it to follow: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=200859

Answer (score 2):

This is not an actual solution but for time being I added this line of code in view pager and its working:

```
android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

so my full layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_search" />
```